# Detected memory leaks! CwinThread

Tags: mfc

My ThreadFunc very simple, buid ok, but when I click OK button, program was closed and...
Detected memory leaks! 
Here my code:

```
UINT ThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
    return 1;
}
void CNhanDienBanTayDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    pThread = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc,this);      
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the AFX thread and exit your application, without waiting for that thread to finish. The thread is not deleted, so there is your leak.

Comment: oh, thank you :D. This my first time i use MFC. I dont know that line will exit application
CDialogEx::OnOK();